# Golang FTP EPRT Error

Tags: go, ftp, ftp-client

I'm currently trying to send a file to an FTP server in Go utilizing the github.com/secsy/goftp library.  I'm able to connect/authenticate against the server without issue, but I'm having trouble sending the file.  There is not much context around the the error that I could find.  I've tried manually forcing the client to use active and passive transfers without any success.  Any ideas?

```
config := goftp.Config{
    User:               "username",
    Password:           "password",
    ConnectionsPerHost: 1,
    Timeout:            10 * time.Second,
    IPv6Lookup:         false,
    ActiveTransfers:    false,
    Logger:             os.Stderr,
}

client, err := goftp.DialConfig(config, "server_hostname:2121")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error connecting to FTP")
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    os.Exit(1)
}

uploadFile, err := os.Open(fileLocation)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error opening file for FTP")
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    os.Exit(1)
}

err = client.Store(ftpPath, uploadFile)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error FTP'ing File")
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Here are the messages posted from the client:

```
goftp: 0.000 #1 opening control connection to [server]:2121
goftp: 0.056 #1 sending command USER username
goftp: 0.084 #1 got 331-User name ok, password required
goftp: 0.084 #1 sending command PASS ******
goftp: 0.111 #1 got 230-Password ok, continue
goftp: 0.112 #1 sending command FEAT
goftp: 0.137 #1 got 211-211-Extensions supported:
goftp: 0.137 #1 was ready
goftp: 0.137 #1 sending command TYPE I
goftp: 0.137 #1 error reading response: short response:  EPRT
Error FTP'ing File
error reading response: short response:  EPRT
exit status 1
```

Here are the messages posted from the server:

```
2017/02/07 13:14:26 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: Connection Established
2017/02/07 13:14:26 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: 220 Welcome to the Go FTP Server
2017/02/07 13:14:26 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: USER username
2017/02/07 13:14:26 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: 331 User name ok, password required
2017/02/07 13:14:26 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: PASS ****
2017/02/07 13:14:26 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: 230 Password ok, continue
2017/02/07 13:14:27 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: FEAT 
2017/02/07 13:14:27 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: 211 211-Extensions supported:
 EPRT
 EPSV
211 END
2017/02/07 13:14:27 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: TYPE I
2017/02/07 13:14:27 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: 200 Type set to binary
2017/02/07 13:14:27 3c2634d4f643fe779c9a: Connection Terminated
```

Comment: Is your client reading _all_ of the lines of the multi-line `FEAT` response?  That fact that the message "error reading response: short response:  EPRT" is logged _after_ sending `TYPE I` suggests that your client code _assumes_ just a single line FTP response for all commands, which is not the case for `FEAT`...

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure I have any option to set or anyway to tell the client otherwise.  I'm also not telling it to set the transfer type, as it seems to be inferred when I issue the call to store.  Any ideas on what I could look at to validate or verify this?

Comment: I just took a look at the `goftp` client code; I'm not sure it's [doing the right thing](https://github.com/secsy/goftp/blob/master/persistent_connection.go#L207); multi-line FTP responses end with "\r\n", not just "\n".  Will try to find some time to reproduce this issue locally.